# Android onDestroy and Onstop not guarantied to be called

Tags: android, kotlin

In my android app (written in kotlin) I would like to do some data saving when my activity is destroyed. But I have a problem. I've done researching and found out that onDestroy() and onStop() methods are not guarantied to be called. So practically my activity can be destroyed without calling onDestroy() method which would be disaster for me.
Please, does anyone have some gentle solution for this problem?

Comment: Where did you read that onStop() is not guaranteed to be called?

Comment: Oh damn. I just found out that for devices running 4.0 and lower onStop() is not guarantied and for higher than 4.0 it is. OK cool those are practically all devices :)

Comment: but @BömachtBlau what is than the use of onDestroy method if it is never guarantied to be called. I can not see any scenario I would use it... It looks so unsafe and i don't like unsafe in programming...

Comment: onDestroy() is called e.g. when the Activity will be destroyed because of a configuration change

Comment: Over the years things change now and then - I just re-read [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#ondestroy) to be sure how things are today

Comment: Yes that is what OS does. But we as programmers should never override and use that method since its unsafe? That's what I meant

Comment: Yes ok. Maybe one day it will become safe like onStop became safe from 4.0 and higher API

Comment: OK thanks for the talk and your time, you helped me

Comment: In the guide it says "The onDestroy() callback should release all resources that have not yet been released by earlier callbacks such as onStop()" ... so if the Activity should still be holding on to something now would be the time... but I agree, you won't need to overide onDestroy() in most cases.... and you're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some additional information:

The purpose of overriding `onDestroy` is if you need to clean up leakable resources, like something that uses native memory or a spawned Thread that is holding onto object references. It will never "become safe" like you suggested in the comments because using it as a hook for saving state is not its purpose. The reason it is not guaranteed to be called is that if the OS is shutting down your application completely, the entire heap of memory for your app is released, in which case it would be redundant to call it.

The majority of apps should never need to override it because most apps don't allocate memory directly, and there are better techniques for handling asynchronous work than spawning Threads directly.

Comment: I understand you, you want to say that it is best to use it for example to unregister receivers, listeners, etc to avoid memory leaks. That is totally fine.
But in android there are often cases where you must do some action when Activity is being destroyed and those are the cases that are confusing for me. 
Are you sure the only reason onDestroy() may not be called is because OS killed my whole application?

Comment: That's the only situation described in the documentation, but it's worded in a way that doesn't necessarily guarantee it. Typically, the things you must do when an Activity is destroyed is tear down stuff that you set up in `onCreate()`, such as unregistering listeners, in which case, it's fine to do it in `onDestroy()`. For example, if you set up a SharedPreferencesOnChangedListener in `onCreate()`, it makes sense to unregister it in the mirror method `onDestroy()`.

Comment: But in modern Android recommended practices, most stuff like that will be in a ViewModel. That's part of the reason I said it's not common to need to override `onDestroy()`. I'm not sure what other kinds of things you're thinking of that might need to be done when an Activity is destroyed.

Comment: For example In my company's applicartion, we have PlayGameActivity in which we start game to play. We overrride OnDestroy() method so we can call client.refresh() to refresh our balance when we finish with playing game and come back to another activity. So this is not "listener unregistering" case but still we need OnDestroy to do this.
Also I would like to ask you. If we have fragment, is it true that we can use onDetach() in these kind of situations (is it guarantied to be called?) and do all our work here.

Comment: `onPause` and `onStop` are always guaranteed to be called (except in a crash). In a low memory situation, Android can shut down your app when it is in the background so that’s why you can’t rely on `onDestroy` for saving anything. You never know for sure when your app goes to the background (`onStop`) that it will come back without first being shut down, so you have to assume it might be and save in onPause or onStop to be sure. I’m not sure about fragment lifecycle guarantees.

Comment: Ooo so when my app is in background and Android OS shuts it down, OnDestroy() will not be called? Now I got you totally what you want to say, this clears it up.
OK thank you for your explanations, you helped me understand this matter!

Answer (score 2):

You are right about [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy())

> do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!

For saving state you should use `onPause()`, `onSaveInstanceState()` or
[onStop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onStop()) - which gets called as soon your Activity is no longer visible to the user.